# Errors happen when using World.destroyBody( Body body )

Tags: box2d, libgdx, body

on Android application using libgdx, when I use World.destroyBody( Body body ) method, once in a while the application suddenly shuts down.

Is there some setting I need to do with body collision or Box2DDebugRenderer before I destroy bodies?

Below is the source I use for destroying bodies.

```
private void deleteUnusedObject( ) {
    for( Iterator<Body> iter = mWorld.getBodies() ; iter.hasNext() ; ){
        Body body = iter.next( ) ;
        if( body.getUserData( ) != null ) {
            Box2DUserData data = (Box2DUserData) body.getUserData( ) ;
            if( ! data.getActFlag() ) {
                if( body != null ) {
                    mWorld.destroyBody( body ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Why would you check if the `body != null` in the inner if statement when it is first used in your first if statement `body.getUserData() != null`.

Second, what does `mWorld.destroyBody( body );` do? Do you have any other threads running?

Comment: Do you do any contact filtering? When do you call deleteUnusedObjects? Are you sure youre not storing and using any references to destroyed bodies somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to remove a box2d body from the world in libgdx?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/what-is-the-proper-way-to-remove-a-box2d-body-from-the-world-in-libgdx)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to destroy the body in a CollisonEvent, this happens mid-step so you can't do that.  Your best bet is to build a list of objects you would like to destroy and have them removed next frame.

Comment: This is most likely the problem. @minami I did post a solution here that you would need to call outside the world.step() http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/what-is-the-proper-way-to-remove-a-box2d-body-from-the-world-in-libgdx/27136#27136

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem in libgdx. But I found an alternate solution about this is.
The following is the way to work same as destroyBody

```
world.step(0,0,0);
body.setActive(false);
```

this will made body inactive in the physics world and in the dispose method we destroy the body.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not trying to destroy the body inside of world.step(). If you are destroying it from a ContactListener or something similar, you'll have to mark the body to be destroyed later and not during world.setp().

Answer (score 0):

In your render method check if the world is locked, with world.islocked(), if it isn´t locked, and call immediatly the destroy body.

I suppose that you error is an assertion from Box2D

```
render(float arg0)
{
       if(!world.isLocked())
       {
            destroy your bodies here
            .
            .
            .

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do it, i read it in the Box2D manual. You have to call this just after     CURRENT_WORLD.step(..,...,...);

```
Iterator<Body> i = mWorld.getBodies();
Body node=i.next();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Body oBj=node;
    node=i.next();
    Box2DUserData data = (Box2DUserData ) oBj.getUserData();
    if(data!=null  &&  !data.getActFlag()){
        mWorld.destroyBody(oBj);                
    }
}
```