# How to move a body from one world to another?

Tags: c++, box2d

I have a Box2D world for each level in my game. When a level is completed, I want the player to be removed from the completed level's world and added to the next level's world. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here ...

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies

Then end with a sprinkling of ...

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/bodies

I'm guessing the latter you already did, so essentially you are just doing the first part in reverse.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to destroy the body and re-create it in order to use it in a new World? It seems a tad inefficient that way to say the least.

Comment: That's usually how physics engines work ... you can add things and remove things but its generally hard to get hold of a part of the world. That said ... this is C++ ... i live in a c# world so maybe you can somehow geta  pointer and move that over to the new world somehow. I've never seen that though.

Comment: hmmm ... how about something like this ... http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/what-is-the-proper-way-to-remove-a-box2d-body-from-the-world-in-libgdx?rq=1

Comment: looks like in the solution he gets a ref to the body ... so you just need to pass that to your new world right?

Comment: The thing is, there's no way to pass a reference. There's no `AddBody()` function - just a `CreateBody()`.

Comment: Having an `AddBody()` function implies that it's possible to reference the same body in different physics worlds.
I can't really imagine why you would want to do that.

Comment: @TimothyGroote IIRC some physics enginges allow remove the body from the original world before adding it to the new world, so the scenario you mentioned shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: they *allow* it, yes. but that still means you're capable of hooking it up to two different worlds. there's no way you can guarantee decent behavior of that body if it is hooked up to two worlds.

Comment: @TimothyGroote Ah sorry, I meant that they _force_ the removal, not allow.