# In Box2D, how can I SetTransform of a body without getting an IsLocked assertion error?

Tags: box2d

I've created a bullet body and stored a reference to it in `herobody`:

```
bDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bDef.position.Set(herobody->GetPosition().x, herobody->GetPosition().y);
b = world->CreateBody(&bDef);
b2FixtureDef fixturebDef;
b2CircleShape circlebShape;
circlebShape.m_radius = 0.05;
fixturebDef.shape = &circlebShape;
b->CreateFixture(&fixturebDef);
```

I'm trying to change the current position of the bullet. I tried to use `SetTransform` but I get an error `Assertion failed: (IsLocked() == false)` during `world->step` in my `update` method.

```
// This doesn't work. Causes the above assertion.
/*
b->SetTransform(
  b2Vec2(
    herobody->GetPosition().x,
    herobody->GetPosition().y
  ),
  0
);
*/

// This works, but doesn't set position directly.
b->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(5, 0), b->GetWorldCenter(),true);
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `SetTransform` *before* or *after* your `World::step` call. Make sure it's not inside a Box2D callback, as those happen *inside* the `step`, during which the `World` is locked.

---

Further details:

The `isLocked() == false` assert implies you're attempting to directly change something in the Box2D `World` *during a simulation step*. This could break the simulation, so Box2D guards against it. `SetTransform` directly changes the body's position, so it is disallowed when locked.

`ApplyLinearImpulse` works even when locked, because all it does is register a new impulse that should act on the body, which does not directly change anything. The impulse is only applied on the next world step.

---

If you want the `SetTransform` to in response to some event (not every step), you'll need to introduce some additional state. For example, a `bool shouldResetBallPosition` that the appropriate callback sets to `true`. You can then then check for that inside your update method, with something like—

```
if (shouldResetBallPosition) {
    b->setTransform( ... );
    ...
    shouldResetBallPosition = false;
}
```

Comment: but when i called SetTransform before world::step in update. it update position every second and ApplyLinearImpulse can't work :/

Comment: @dex3 What do you mean by "ApplyLinearImpulse can't work"?

Comment: hero throw ball (applylinearimpulse) and it immediately back to position from (transform) ;/ i would like to do sth like this: If i click button it back to position hero and next throw again

Comment: @dex3 I think I see what you mean: you don't want the `SetPosition` to happen every step, but only in response to something else, like a mouse click. I edited to address that. Does it help?

Comment: is it the only way to do that? or do you have some idea how to storage it and recall ?

Comment: @dex3 If `SetPosition` is disallowed inside `World::step` and the event you want to react to is happening inside the `World::step`, it's inevitable that you'll have to store data for later. The [Box2D manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) recommends in §9.4 "*The recommended practice for processing contact points is to buffer all contact data that you care about and process it after the time step.*" It is talking about the post-solve callback, but the same applies for other callbacks.

Comment: i've got one more question  world->DestroyBody(somebody); should be before World::step or it could be anywhere??

Comment: @dex3 `DestroyBody` also needs to be outside of `World::step`. [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27113/7804) has a solution.